# Python: calculate the sum of a column after splitting the column

Tags: python, split, sum, multiple-columns

I'm new at writing python and thought I would re-write some of my programs that are in perl.
I have a tab delimited file, where columns 9-through the end (which varies) needs to be further split and then the sum of part of that column added

for instance, input (only looking at columns 9-12):

```
0:0:1:0    0:0:2:0    0:0:3:0    0:0:4:0
0:0:1:0    0:0:2:0    0:0:3:0    0:0:4:0
0:0:1:0    0:0:2:0    0:0:3:0    0:0:4:0
0:0:1:0    0:0:2:0    0:0:3:0    0:0:4:0
```

output (sum of each column[2]:

```
4
8
12
16
```

All I've got so far is

```
        datacol = line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
        for element in datacol[9:len(datacol)]:
            splitcol=int(element.split(r":")[2])
            totalcol += splitcol
        print(totalcol)
```

which doesn't work and gives me the sum of column[2] for each row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    mysum = 0
    with open('myfilename','r') as f:
    for line in f:
    mysum += int(line.split()[3])

    line.split() will turn "123  Hammer  20  36" into ["123", "Hammer", "20", "36"].
```

We take the fourth value  36 using the index [3]. This is still a string, and can be converted to an integer using  int or a decimal (floating-point) number using float.

to check for empty lines add the condition if line: in the for loop. In your particular case you might do something like:

```
for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    if len(words)>3:
        mysum += int(words[3])
```

Comment: I may not understand what you wrote, but when I tried it I still get the answer of the sum of the rows (10, 10, 10,10). I would like 4,8,12,16

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
totalcol = [0,0,0,0] #Store sum results in a list
with open('myfilename','r') as f:
for line in f
    #split line and keep columns 9,10,11,12
    #assuming you are counting from 1 and have only 12 columns
    datacol = line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")[8:]  #lists start at index 0!
    #Loop through each column and sum the 3rd element
    for i,element in enumerate(datacol):
        splitcol=int(element.split(":")[2])
        totalcol[i] += splitcol
print(totalcol)
```

Comment: Thanks WombatPM! It works great. I edited it slightly because totalcol=[0,0,0,0] assumes a size of a list. So I made an empty list and created its size based on the number of columns I'm processing.